# If $AA^*=AA$, how to prove $A$ is an Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $AA^*=AA,$ how to prove $A$ is Hermitian?

Answer (score 7):

An arbitrary square matrix $A$ can be written as $B + i C$ where $B = (A + A^*)/2$ and $C = (A - A^*)/(2i)$ are Hermitian.  The given condition
says $AC = 0$, i.e. $B C = -iC^2$.  But $CBC = -iC^3$, and the left side is Hermitian while the right side is only Hermitian if $C = 0$.  Therefore $C = 0$ which means $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Nicely done ${}{}$

Comment: @Robert Israel I see why $C^3 = O$, but can you explain why $C = O$?

Comment: @OpenSeason any nilpotent Hermitian matrix is $0$.

Comment: @OpenSeason quickest proof of this: note that for any matrix $A$, $A$ and $A^*A$ have the same rank.  So, $C$ and $C^2 = C^*C$ have the same rank.  It follows that $C$ and $C^3$ have the same rank.  So, if $C^3 = 0$, then $C = 0$.

Comment: @OpenSeason Maybe quicker: any Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized.  It's obvious for diagonal matrices..